# Thymeleaf layout decorator does not work

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Hi guys i have learning thymeleaf, i do not understand why its not working i read a lot of example and i made it correctly but it does not work. Can somebody tell me what i have missing here?

This is my layout:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
```

```
<link href="webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<th:block layout:fragment="styles">
```

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Decorator Sample</span>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div layout:fragment="page_content"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="webjars/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<th:block layout:fragment="scripts">
```

And this is my index:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" 
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" 
  layout:decorate="~{_layout}">
<body>
    <div layout:fragment="page_content">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: are there any errors?

Comment: #1 I don't recognize a doctype definition. #2 I don't know if it is possible to use non-closing th:block elements. You are using them a lot and maybe that's a problem.

Answer (score 3):

We will need to add the Thymeleaf starter pack to your Spring Boot pom:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

However, starting from Spring Boot 2 this is no longer enough. The Layout Dialect is not part of the starter and we need to add it on our own:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
<artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>    
</dependency>
```

The code examples also use Bootstrap so the webjars need to be added as well:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
<artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
<version>3.3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Just had the same "issue" where the decorator did not seem to take over... Thank you for this, I feel so dumb now

Answer (score 1):

Did you have this in your pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
</dependency>
```